# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken not called if registerForRemoteNotifications called via dispatch_async

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification

On IOS we register for remote notifications and observe the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken callback to get the device token..

However, using the new UNUserNotificationCenter code for Rich notifications, we are using requestAuthorizationWithOptions with a completion handler. The completion handler calls registerForRemoteNotifications, but this is not on the main thread and XCode is complaining that it needs to be.

We then used dispatch_async to call it on the main thread, as below, but if we do, we dont get the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken or didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError callbacks.

Should we ignore the XCode warning and not use dispatch_async, or is there another reason that if we DO we don't get the callbacks ?

Thanks

Shaun

```
 if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) 
    {
        //code for old IOS
    }
    else
    {
        UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        center.delegate = self;
        [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error)
        {
            if( !error ) 
            {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
                Log( "PUSHNOTIF Called Register" );
                });

            } 
            else 
            {
                Log( "PUSHNOTIF Error from request auth" );
            }
        }];
   }
```

Comment: Did you enable pushnotification in capabilities? Is your else block runs?

Comment: We don't get to the else block. Everything works if we don't call registerForRemoteNotifications through dispatch_async. The code below works - we get the delgate callbacks, but XCode complains   

    if( !error ) 
            {
                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
                Log( "PUSHNOTIF Called Register" );
             }

Comment: Further checking has revealed that the didRegisterForRemoteNotificationWithDevToken delegate is not getting called at all as a result of this registerForRemoteNotifications call. It does get called on the next run of the app though, as there is a similar call in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. IS there somethign we have to do differently to call this anywhere other than from within didFinishLaunchingWithOptions ? Maybe the callbacks are not going to the main app delegate ?